# Not able to build project with Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder

When ever I am doing build or clean build, I am getting following error:

```
An internal error occured during:"Searching for Markers"
```

Using Flash Builder 4.6 on Windows 7 with 8 GB RAM.

Comment: I suppose it is FlashBuilder and not flex, but anyway looks like a ide issue: 1. Have you tried reinstalling the ide? 2. create a new project and try to debug, still same error?

Comment: I am keeping reinstalling and creating new project as a last resort. Is there any other way to get rid of.

Comment: only with this message i am not able to point a cause. but creating a new project with just a label inside should be fast. I did not really understood... are new projects working ?

Comment: I didnt try to create a new project yet. Will do and update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Project > Clean...? I get internal build errors all the time and even odder errors where a half dozen or so images won't embed without removing the @Embed('') bits from the source property. Project > Clean... fixes it pretty much every time. The few times it hasn't, unfortunately, I've ended up having to reinstall Flash Builder, which is a royal pain.

EDIT: Woops. This may be what you were referring to with a "clean build". I was thinking it was a vanilla project you were trying to build that was failing. My mistake.